# Is there a way to track button click by Button ID using Komito analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, komito-analytics

I am using Komito Analytics to track Events in Google Analytics.
So far they are doing good.
I would like to create 2 different buttons with different ids or classes and track them separately.
is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs and current implementation, you can use one of the following methods:

1. Enable `trackForms` to track forms submissions and wrap each button in a `<form>` element:

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <button type="submit" name="action1">Button 1</button>
<form>
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <button type="submit" name="action2">Button 2</button>
<form>
```

2. Enable `trackActions` to track CTA actions for links and use links instead of buttons:

```html
<a href="javascript:void('action1')">Links 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void('action2')">Links 2</a>
or
<a href="javascript:'action1';void 0">Links 1</a>
<a href="javascript:'action2';void 0">Links 2</a>
```

Comment: The first option is better and much flexible then the second one

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of clicks on the button with Javascript

```
<button id="komito">komito</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        var btn = document.getElementById("komito");
  
        komito.onclick = function () {
            count++;
console.log(count);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: will this reflect in Google Analytics Events Panel? I have implemented it i can't see any difference

Comment: It will not reflect in your Google Analytics it will show the number of counts where you have placed the code.

With the help of this code, you can see the number of counts in your console. See the Updated code

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with Komito Analytics.